# Authorize.net triggering response code 4 - Held for review - in testing

Tags: authorize.net

I'm trying to figure out how to generate a general response code of 4 in testing with Authorize.net.

This page outlines the testing you can do and I have successfully used this guide for testing other responses: http://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/testing_guide/

The response codes are 1 - 4:

1 = Approved

2 = Declined

3 = Error

4 = Held for Review

Does anyone know how to generate a response code of 4 using the test cards auth.net provides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test account settings, change the avs settings to review.

Comment: I don't have access to the auth.net account. Only the client does. I'll send him a request to do that but I'm not sure he even knows what I'm talking about. This was all set up long before they hired me.

Comment: Do you have a developer account? If so you can test it there.

Comment: Auth.net lets you set up a sandbox account that you can test against with the Testing guide I linked above. There's no indication that I can control the sandbox and set avs settings. https://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/sandbox/

Comment: You should have a login and password for your developer account. From there you can access a normal control panel and set your settings in there. It should function just like a regular account but obviously is fake.

Comment: Created a developer account and tested it. Thanks!